# Xcode git source control - files show up that don't exist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git

When I click commit, there are many files ticked for deletion that don't exist in the project. As a result, when I click commit, I get `error: pathspec '[file]' did not match any file(s) known to git.` for every file like this. I can untick each one but I can't do that every time I commit. How do I get rid of these?

Comment: you should use .gitignore for these files.

Comment: How do I do this? The files don't exist. I think it had something to do with adding a CocoaPods library and then removing it.